# The attribute 'http' may not appear in tag 'meta name= and content=' on AMP page

Tags: html, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

When trying to convert my page to AMP i am getting the following error: `The attribute 'http' may not appear in tag 'meta name= and content='`

Comment: You'd need to provide the HTML to be certain, but it certainly sounds like an unmatched or missing quote or similar typo if the parser is seeing a tag name of "meta name= and content=".

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks for the reply. fixed it by replacing http to https :)

Comment: @adithyasai Please do not use [tag:amp] tag for your questions about AMP pages. Please read the description, this tag is related to RPC protocol, not to Accelerated Mobile pages. Please use [tag:amp-html] or [tag:accelerated-mobile-page]

Comment: @VadimKotov sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http** is not allowed in amp meta tags. Changing it to **https** will work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution is: AMP meta tags should not contain any link with 'HTTP' it should be only 'https'. In development, we usually use something like 'http://localhost:7666/img.jpg' but the same may work when it is deployed in production (if it is on https) like 'https://xyg.com/img.jpg'. For me it worked once i deployed to production as its working with 'https'.

**To be simple the solution is to change 'HTTP' to 'https'**